# how to read line by line in android?

Tags: java, android, file-handling

i am using this code.

```
try{
          // Open the file that is the first 
          // command line parameter
          FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("config.txt");
          // Get the object of DataInputStream
          DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
          while ((br.readLine()) != null) {
              temp1 = br.readLine();
              temp2 = br.readLine();

          }

          in.close();
    }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Exception", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), temp1+temp2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

but this is showing exception and is not updating temp1 and temp2.

Comment: do you want to store the same line in 2 different variables? or you just want to save the last 2 lines in temp1 and temp2?

Comment: wanna save first two lines of file in two different variables.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The exception you see - that I would strongly recommend a) to catch as a specific type, e.g. `IOException`, and b) to log or show with a message or a stack trace, and c) at least to check for in LogCat, from the DDMS perspective if you are programming with Eclipse - is probably due to Android not finding the `config.txt` file you are trying to open. Usually, for the simplest cases such as yours, files that are private to an application are opened using `openFileInput` - [see the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileInput%28java.lang.String%29) for details.

Apart from the exception, your reading loop is defective: you need to initialize an empty string before entering, and fill it in the `while` condition.

```
String line = "";
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    // do something with the line you just read, e.g.
    temp1 = line;
    temp2 = line;
}
```

However, you don't need a loop if you just want to save the first two lines in different variables.

```
String line = "";
if ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    temp1 = line;
if ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    temp2 = line;
```

As others have already pointed out, calling `readLine` consumes a line, so if your `config.txt` file contains only one line your code consumes it on the `while` condition, then `temp1` and `temp2` get `null` assigned because there's no more text to read.

Comment: I am using this 
    FileInputStream fstream = new openFileInput("config.txt");
but its not working. it can't resolve openFileInput thing.

Comment: As you see from the documentation linked in my answer, `openFileInput` is a method of `Context`, which `Activity` is derived from. Thus, if you are using the snippet in an activity, `openFileInput` should be already available for you. Otherwise, you need to pass a `Context` instance to the method or class where you want to read the file.

Answer (score 1):

```
try{
      // Open the file that is the first 
      // command line parameter
      FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("config.txt");
      // Get the object of DataInputStream
      DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
      String line = "";
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
          temp1 = line;
          temp2 = line;

      }

      in.close();
}catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Exception", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), temp1+temp2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

br.readLine() in while already consumes a line.

Try this

```
    LineNumberReader reader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader("config.txt")));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        //doProcessLine
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to save the first two lines you have to do:

```
try
{
    // Open the file that is the first
    // command line parameter
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("config.txt");
    // Get the object of DataInputStream
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String line = "";
    if((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        temp1 = line;
    if((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        temp2 = line;   
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: actually its showing exception because it can't find "config.txt". but if i use "FileInputStream fstream = new openFileInput("config.txt");" then its not recognizing it.

Comment: Ok. That's another problem then. anyway, that code is what you need to get the first 2 lines of the file (when it does exist). :)

Comment: yeah they exist actually. I saw them separately.